# Fusion for length-indexed linked lists

Tags: haskell, optimization

I have the standard `Vect` type:

```
module Vect where

data Nat = Z | S Nat
data Vect (n :: Nat) (a :: Type) where
  VNil :: Vect Z a
  VCons :: a -> Vect n a -> Vect (S n) a
```

And I have these functions on it:

```
foldVect :: forall (p :: Nat -> Type) n a.
            p Z ->
            (forall m. a -> p m -> p (S m)) ->
            Vect n a -> p n
foldVect n c = go
  where go :: forall l. Vect l a -> p l
        go VNil = n
        go (VCons x xs) = x `c` go xs

newtype FVect a n = FVect { unFVect :: Vect n a }
buildVect :: forall n a.
             (forall (p :: Nat -> Type).
              p Z ->
              (forall m. a -> p m -> p (S m)) ->
              p n
             ) -> Vect n a
buildVect f = unFVect $ f (FVect VNil) $ \x (FVect xs) -> FVect $ x `VCons` xs
```

I attempted to recreate (part of) the machinery from `base` that allows for list fusion:

```
instance Functor (Vect n) where
    fmap = mapVect
    {-# INLINE fmap #-}

mapVect :: forall n a b. (a -> b) -> (Vect n a -> Vect n b)
mapVect _f VNil = VNil
mapVect f (VCons x xs) = f x `VCons` mapVect f xs
mapFB :: forall (p :: Nat -> Type) n a b. (forall m. b -> p m -> p (S m)) -> (a -> b) -> a -> p n -> p (S n)
mapFB cons f = \x ys -> cons (f x) ys
{-# INLINE [0] mapFB #-}
{-# NOINLINE [0] mapVect #-}
{-# RULES "mapVect" [~1] forall f xs. mapVect f xs = buildVect (\nil cons -> foldVect nil (mapFB cons f) xs) #-}

{-# INLINE [0] foldVect #-}
-- base has this; I don't think it does anything without a "refolding" rule on mapVect
{-# INLINE [0] buildVect #-}
{-# RULES "foldVect/buildVect" forall (nil :: p Z)
                                      (cons :: forall m. a -> p m -> p (S m))
                                      (f :: forall (q :: Nat -> Type).
                                            q Z ->
                                            (forall m. a -> q m -> q (S m)) ->
                                            q n
                                      ).
          foldVect nil cons (buildVect f) = f nil cons
  #-}
```

And then

```
module Test where
import Vect

test :: Vect n Int -> Vect n Int
test = fmap (*5) . fmap (+2)
```

No fusion happens. If I pass `-ddump-simpl`, I see that `foldVect` and `buildVect` have already been inlined, but...

1. The `INLINE`s are phased so that they don't interfere with fusion anyway. (After all, this is how `base` does it for `[]`)
2. Replacing the `INLINE [0]`s with `NOINLINE` paints a rather stunning image:

   ```
   test
     = \ (@ (n_a141 :: Nat)) (x_X1lK :: Vect n_a141 Int) ->
         buildVect
           @ n_a141
           @ Int
           (\ (@ (p_X1jl :: Nat -> *))
              (nil_X11K [OS=OneShot] :: p_X1jl 'Z)
              (cons_X11M [OS=OneShot]
                 :: forall (m :: Nat). Int -> p_X1jl m -> p_X1jl ('S m)) ->
              foldVect
                @ p_X1jl
                @ n_a141
                @ Int
                nil_X11K
                (\ (@ (m_a1i5 :: Nat))
                   (x1_aYI :: Int)
                   (ys_aYJ [OS=OneShot] :: p_X1jl m_a1i5) ->
                   cons_X11M
                     @ m_a1i5
                     (case x1_aYI of { GHC.Types.I# x2_a1l5 ->
                      GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.*# x2_a1l5 5#)
                      })
                     ys_aYJ)
                (buildVect
                   @ n_a141
                   @ Int
                   (\ (@ (p1_a1i0 :: Nat -> *))
                      (nil1_a10o [OS=OneShot] :: p1_a1i0 'Z)
                      (cons1_a10p [OS=OneShot]
                         :: forall (m :: Nat). Int -> p1_a1i0 m -> p1_a1i0 ('S m)) ->
                      foldVect
                        @ p1_a1i0
                        @ n_a141
                        @ Int
                        nil1_a10o
                        (\ (@ (m_a1i5 :: Nat))
                           (x1_aYI :: Int)
                           (ys_aYJ [OS=OneShot] :: p1_a1i0 m_a1i5) ->
                           cons1_a10p
                             @ m_a1i5
                             (case x1_aYI of { GHC.Types.I# x2_a1lh ->
                              GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.+# x2_a1lh 2#)
                              })
                             ys_aYJ)
                        x_X1lK)))
   ```

   Everything is *right there*, but the simplifier is just not having it.

If I inspect the rule itself, I see this

```
"foldVect/buildVect"
    forall (@ (p_aYG :: Nat -> *))
           (@ (n_aYJ :: Nat))
           (@ a_aYH)
           (nil_aYD :: p_aYG 'Z)
           (cons_aYE :: forall (m :: Nat). a_aYH -> p_aYG m -> p_aYG ('S m))
           (f_aYF
              :: forall (q :: Nat -> *).
                 q 'Z -> (forall (m :: Nat). a_aYH -> q m -> q ('S m)) -> q n_aYJ).
      foldVect @ p_aYG
               @ n_aYJ
               @ a_aYH
               nil_aYD
               cons_aYE
               (buildVect
                  @ n_aYJ
                  @ a_aYH
                  (\ (@ (p1_a156 :: Nat -> *))
                     (ds_d1io :: p1_a156 'Z)
                     (ds1_d1ip
                        :: forall (m :: Nat). a_aYH -> p1_a156 m -> p1_a156 ('S m)) ->
                     f_aYF @ p1_a156 ds_d1io ds1_d1ip))
      = f_aYF @ p_aYG nil_aYD cons_aYE
```

It appears that the issue is that the argument to `buildVect` needs to be a lambda abstraction of a very specific form, and I'm having trouble constructing a system of rewrites where that ends up happening.

How do I get fusion to work?

(I don't know if this is useful or even correct; I'm just doing this to see if I can.)

Comment: Have you tried it with a non-indexed datatype? ie `data MyList a where { Nil :: MyList a; Cons :: a -> MyList a -> MyList a }`. Just trying to narrow down what might have gone wrong

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Well, `[]` definitely works. Writing out my own `List` and functions also works (even when I implement `buildList` with a `newtype` to simulate the dance for `Vect`) (but only if the function where fusion is expected is in a different module (cue big WTF from me)). I've been testing the `Vect` version with two different modules, too (edited that in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, `newtype`s save the day whenever the compiler is being bullheaded:

```
module Vect where
-- everything else the same...
newtype VectBuilder n a = VectBuilder { runVectBuilder :: forall (p :: Nat -> Type).
                                                          p Z ->
                                                          (forall m. a -> p m -> p (S m)) ->
                                                          p n
                                      }

buildVect' :: forall n a. VectBuilder n a -> Vect n a
buildVect' f = unFVect $
                runVectBuilder f (FVect VNil) $ \x (FVect xs) -> FVect $ x `VCons` xs
{-# INLINE [0] buildVect' #-}
buildVect :: forall n a.
             (forall (p :: Nat -> Type).
              p Z ->
              (forall m. a -> p m -> p (S m)) ->
              p n
             ) -> Vect n a
buildVect f = buildVect' (VectBuilder f)
{-# INLINE buildVect #-}

{-# RULES "foldVect/buildVect'" forall (nil :: p Z)
                                       (cons :: forall m. a -> p m -> p (S m))
                                       (f :: VectBuilder n a).
                                foldVect nil cons (buildVect' f) = runVectBuilder f nil cons
  #-}
-- compiler no longer has a chance to muck up the LHS by eta expanding f because
-- f "isn't" a function anymore

-- rule for mapVect goes unchanged, so I guess that's evidence that this is totally transparent
```

```
module Test where
import Vect
test :: Vect n Int -> Vect n Int
test = fmap (*5) . fmap (+2)
```

```
Rec {
-- RHS size: {terms: 19, types: 31, coercions: 13, joins: 0/0}
Test.test_go [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: forall (l :: Nat). Vect l Int -> FVect Int l
[GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=<S,1*U>]
Test.test_go
  = \ (@ (l_a14W :: Nat)) (ds_d1jk :: Vect l_a14W Int) ->
      case ds_d1jk of {
        VNil co_a14Y -> (Vect.$WVNil @ Int) `cast` <Co:4>;
        VCons @ n2_a151 co_a152 x_aYE xs_aYF ->
          (Vect.VCons
             @ ('S n2_a151)
             @ Int
             @ n2_a151
             @~ <Co:2>
             (case x_aYE of { GHC.Types.I# x1_a1xr ->
              GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.*# (GHC.Prim.+# x1_a1xr 2#) 5#) -- success!
              })
             ((Test.test_go @ n2_a151 xs_aYF) `cast` <Co:3>))
          `cast` <Co:4>
      }
end Rec }

-- RHS size: {terms: 4, types: 5, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
Test.test1 :: forall (n :: Nat). Vect n Int -> FVect Int n
[GblId,
 Arity=1,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=<S,1*U>,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=1,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)}]
Test.test1
  = \ (@ (n_a1wd :: Nat)) (x_X1xa :: Vect n_a1wd Int) ->
      Test.test_go @ n_a1wd x_X1xa

-- RHS size: {terms: 1, types: 0, coercions: 9, joins: 0/0}
test :: forall (n :: Nat). Vect n Int -> Vect n Int
[GblId,
 Arity=1,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=<S,1*U>,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Value=True, ConLike=True,
         WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(arity=0,unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)}]
test = Test.test1 `cast` <Co:9>
```

Moral of the story: sufficiently highly ranked types make the `RULES` system implode, so give GHC some help with `newtype`s, even if they aren't otherwise necessary.

Comment: I wonder how reliable this will be. GHC likes to simplify coercions away.

Comment: @dfeuer Once the `RULE` is made, it should work always. The issue was because GHC had eta-expanded the function inside the `RULE`, forcing it to be a specific kind of lambda abstraction. Now, I see that it's a variable, which will match any expression, and therefore always work. Thus, *in this case*, it should be fine. The real question is whether using a `newtype` will work for *all* such `RULES` that otherwise break this way. My gut feeling is "yes", considering that this case is pretty "bad" and yet works out, but compilers are dark beasts.